# Wordpress - pre_get_posts filtering by the count of dynamic keys

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a new sortable column in my custom post type called offers_made.

I now want to sort by the amount of dynamic keys each post_id has within its meta.

**For example:**
Each post could have a dynamic key such as _kf_offers_1, _kf_offers_9, _kf_offers_12.

So I want to return the value of 3 on my column header. Here is what I have so far, but I dont think I'm going to achieve it this way because I dont think pre_get_posts works this way?

When I click 'sort ASC' in the column header - The values of each key are being displayed but just not sorting.

```
function sortable_offers_orderby( $query ) {

    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;
 
    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');
 
    if( 'offers_made' == $orderby ) {

        $meta_query = array(
            'relation'  => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'           => '_kf_offers_',
                'compare_key'   => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key'           => '_kf_offers_',
                'compare'       => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),

        );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sortable_offers_orderby' );
```

Hope this makes sense,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `pre_get_posts` only works with arguments that WP Query accepts, so you are correct that it doesn't work the way you want. HOWEVER, what you can do is when a post is saved/updated, you can create a custom meta field that holds the count of offers - then with that data, you can use `pre_get_posts` to sort, since you'll have meta data to use.

Comment: I did think of this as a solution originally - but didnt know if there was another workaround. Thanks for your help.